# I cannot boot into windows 7 after installing ubuntu. BIOS-Boot partition error

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, windows-7

I've been scratching my head for hours, and am completely lost. I have ubuntu installed on a separate drive, and 5 other drives I use with windows 7. I ran Boot-Repair with "Recommended Repair" and came across this error:

```
GPT detected. Please create a BIOS-Boot partition.
```

I also created a bootinfo summary, which can be viewed here: http://paste2.org/f9ZBXUHw

I have no idea how to create a BIOS-Boot partition, or where to begin.

How can I change the grub boot order so I can choose to boot into Windows 7 or Ubuntu?

Comment: @AnwarShah I managed to figure this out. I have ubuntu running as a virtual machine with the help of [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads)

Answer (score 0):

Recently installed in dual boot mode Windows 10 + Ubuntu 16.04 with GPT partition table.

I used [Rufus](https://rufus.akeo.ie/?locale=pt_BR) tool and followed this YouTube guide [Dual Boot UBUNTU 16.04 LTS & Windows 10 :UEFI](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y_44k6er-5A)